# Is Caliburn.Micro 4.0 still using a Bootstrapper?

Tags: caliburn.micro, netcoreapp3.0

I'm trying to use Caliburn.Micro 4.0.102-alpha with .Net Core 3.0
But there is no BootstrapperBase.

So I have to ask: Is there now another concept or is the class missing in the alpha version?

- Is it too early to test Caliburn.Micro with .Net Core 3.0?
- Is there an other MVVM Framework available to use with .Net Core 3.0?

Your opinion or solution is very welcome :-)

Comment: partially answer my question: BootstrapperBase is still available (seen in CM source code) But too less experience to get it to work in core3 ;-)